# How to run someone else's project on my phone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I just started working as the second person developing an app, and this app has an iPhone component, a WatchKit component, and a daily views component. I was told to use my personal developer profile and that I should be able to run the app on my phone from Xcode, but this is not working. I get the error

> An App ID with Identifier appname.company.app.watchapp is not available. Please enter a different string.

But this turns out to be a rabbit hole because it first makes me change the name of each portion of the app's id, then it starts giving me an error about the overall project id. What's the smart way to do this? I've tried different things on different days to no avail and am not finding much online. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Surely there's some standard and reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to solve this:

1) Indeed change all app ids to something your own developer profile can match. Note that you cannot publish the apps to the App Store with the changed names, at least not as new versions of the old apps.

2) Get the original p12 files (Developer/Production Certificate + Private Key) and  the profiles from the original developer. For the development and ad hoc profiles your device id should also be included in the profiles.